# Resources.getIdentifier(), possible values of deftype argument?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand an Android app that performs computations on investment portfolios. The portfolios are stored in `res/values/portfolio.xml`:

[image]

When a button is pressed in the app, the portfolio data is retrieved as follows:

```
String portfolioName = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.portfolioName)).getText().toString();
Resources res = getResources();
String[] data = res.getStringArray(res.getIdentifier(portfolioName, "array", this.getPackageName()));
```

I found the Android documentation on the [String Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) resource type that explains the syntax of the `portfolio.xml` file, and it explains why the `name` attribute should be used as the first argument of `getIdentifier()`:

> “The filename is arbitrary. The `<string-array>` element's `name` will be used as the resource ID.”

But I haven't found any documentation that explains how you know what you're supposed to put for the `defType`argument of `getIdentifier` (other than that it's a string). In the provided example, `"array"` works, but where does it come from? And what are the possible values of 'defType' in general?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getIdentifier` returns the `id` of the resource for the given resource name. typeDef refers to the type of the `Resource` (read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)). Keep in mind that the  content of `res` is parsed at compile time and the R.java class is generated from the result of this parsing. In the end what you are looking for is a field declared in that class. I don't know the internal implementation, but if you provide `array` as res type, android will look up only on `R.array`, instead than on the whole `R`

Comment: Yes, this document is what I was looking for -- thank you. I will need additional time to assimilate the additional information you have provided. Thanks!