# How to set name of dimension as string with index in a loop

Tags: java, android

New to Java. Basically trying to get the name of the dimension using the index (As I have numbers in the titles of the dimensions). How do I do this? Example of mock code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_STEPS; i++) {
    getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen."set_up_" + i +"_animation_width")
}
```

Comment: use [getResource().getIdentifier()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756896/resources-getidentifier-possible-values-of-deftype-argument)

Answer (score 1):

Make an integer array of dimensions and loop through the array.

An Example code:-

```
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.ic_heart,
        R.drawable.ic_feedback,
        R.drawable.ic_message,
        R.drawable.ic_menu_share,
        R.drawable.ic_google_play,
};

for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    //imageId[i] << will give the drawables
}
```